# Scala : Idiomatic way of removing set of suffixes (substrings) from a String

Tags: scala

I'm looking for an idiomatic way of stripping set of suffixes (substrings) from a string in Scala.

```
val inputString = "abc@xyz.com"
val suffixes = List("\"", "@xyz.com")
```

Basically, the suffixes list is loaded externally and hence not static. Therefore I cannot use the approach of chaining stripSuffix methods

(P.S. - I'll remove the starting " using inputString.stripPrefix("\"")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could used a `foldLeft` to along with the `.stripSuffix()` function to iterate over your dynamic list of suffixes and strip them from your string one-by-one.

```
val inputString = "abc@xyz.com"
val suffixes = List("\"", "@xyz.com")
val strippedString = suffixes.foldLeft(inputString) { (string, suffix ) => 
    string.stripSuffix(suffix)
}
```

Outputs: `abc`

With this approach the order of your suffixes will impact your output.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that doesn't depend on the suffix list order

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex
val pattern = s"(${suffixes.map(s => Regex.quote(s)).mkString("|")})+$$"
inputString.replaceAll(pattern, "")
```

Though this could be quite inefficient if your suffix list is long since it compiles the whole list into one big regex.